# SQL Dynamic column value allocation from column name reference

Tags: sql, t-sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Input table looks as below which has various conversions, but reported only on one conversion (defined in report_field)
[image]

Output table has reported_conversion which is derived based on report_field
[image]

What's the best way of coding to achieve this?

Comment: Please clarify if this is T-SQL or Snowflake SQL. You have both tags. In either case, you'd probably want to use a CASE ... WHEN block on the REPORT_FIELD to chose the CONVERSION column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[CASE expression](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/case.html) could be used:

```
SELECT *
     ,CASE report_field 
           WHEN 'conversion1' THEN conversion1
           WHEN 'conversion2' THEN conversion2
           WHEN 'conversion3' THEN conversion3
      END AS reported_conversion       
FROM tab;
```

or [DECODE](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/decode.html)

```
SELECT *, DECODE(report_field,
                 'conversion1', conversion1
                 'conversion2', conversion2
                 'conversion3', conversion3)
FROM tab
```

Comment: there can be more conversion fields and hardcoding mayn't work